“Android compatibility verification FAILED”
I installed Sophos Intercept X for Mobile on a new Tablet.  
Intercept X is showing: 

Android compatibility verification FAILED” indicates the Android OS on the tablet is not validated according to Google's validation tools.  It might not be an unofficial Android version itself - an unofficial Android version is installed - but instead the device might have been rooted or there are key Google apps missing.  Since Sophos Intercept X for Mobile is supposed to ensure that your device is secure and protected, it reports anything that could be a vulnerability.

a) (key Google apps missing) I followed online instructions to find missing Google apps - "How to check missing Google apps on Android 13 tablet" but none were listed in the subsequent search. Also, check within Google Play with no missing apps shown.  
b) (device might have been rooted )I used a program from the Google Play Store to check if the unit is Rooted. Result "Pad_6S_Pro is not rooted" Running Android 8.1.0 (Oreo)  
c) (unofficial Android version) The Supplier of the tablet states an official version of Android 13 is installed.
Sophos Technical Support stated:

You may choose to ignore the check at your discretion. but I would not trust the device for handling or storing sensitive personal information or banking if you are not able to address the reason why it it is reporting the compatibility failure.

I am at a loss as to how to proceed to determine the reason for Sophos Intercept X for Mobile warning “Android compatibility verification FAILED”.  
Any ideas would be most welcome. Thank you 
(I have used Sophos Intercept X for Mobile on my Mobile for many years without the warning mentioned about showing.)

Thank you for the reply Robert.
It was advertised as a Xiaomi Pad_6S_Pro, as my mobile was Xiaomi I ordered the tablet. After the tablet arrived I noticed the name Xiaomi wasn't shown, and checking further the price was lower, and as you say Andoird 13 instead of 14.
The Integrity API Checker Failed 'X Meets_Device_Integrity' & 'X Meets_Strong_Integrity' - passed ' ✓ Meets_Basic_Integrity".
At a loss as to what to do next - any advice would be welcome

I appreciate the support Robert.
After I received the Tablet and there were no Xiaomi markings I checked the pricing and the technical specification and noticed the differences in both.
I've already linked the device to my Google account, can the Reset under settings "Erase all data (factory reset)' clean out all private data that has accumulated?
Is the device risky to use from the view of being vulnerable to hacking or other impacts?
Apologies for troubling you Robert, but I have no idea about the impact of how to handle the situation.

Based on the name Pad_6S_Pro you seem to have bought is as Xiaomi Pad 6S Pro 12.4. According to GSMarena this device was released with Android 14, therefore it is strange that your device claims to run on Android 13.
Also considering the result of Google Play Integrity check using Device Integrity Check app which fails in 2 of 3 tests, your device is with 99.9% a fake. Every stock Google Android device has to pass all three tests, especially the test "Meets_Strong_Integrity" is the most strict test. Any rooted, manipulated or somehow changed device will end up in this test to fail. Note that the fake OS may also manipulate the display of those test apps.
The result of Sophos Intercept X that it is running Android 8.1.0 (Oreo) is with a high probability correct. The OS itself of fake device is manipulated to display the fake results. Some times the OS even manipulates common system info apps to display the fake results.
Note that a fake device is not only a hardware problem. As mentioned the installed OS is manipulated. Therefore it is possible that common security measures of Android are disabled or non-functional.
It is also possible that the installed OS contains adware, malware or backdoor software like a remote controlling software.
If a factory reset can clear all your data is unknown as the OS is manipulated.
Conclusion your device is with a high probability a fake. Get it back to the vendor and demand to get your money back.

Thank you Robert - I appreciate the support and great help - thank you for your time spent on replying.
A refund has been promised by the site the product was purchased from.
Still - issues with return costs by the main supplier! I am working on that.
I will try to run the factory reset. Other than that I guess that is the best I can do.
Is there a way to remove the link to the Google account before trying the factory reset? A concern based on the potential of data not being cleared by a factory reset?

@Padsr In addition to removing account you can terminate the logon session on server side. Each device uses an own access token, therefore you can terminate logon sessions on server side. This means even if someone would mange to recover the access token from the device, it would not work anymore. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3067630

I appreciate the reply, thank you. - this tablet is giving me more grey hairs! Apologies for bothering you still, but I wondered if - prior to terminating logon on the server side - is there any action to be closed or removed from the tablet first in relation to this server logon termination?

@Padsr I would first remove the account on device side and then check if it had been removed on server side. Afterwards I would remove all apps installed by you. May be except a tool that overwrites the flash memory with random data to reduce the risk that if the factory reset doesn't fully work the chance that something important is left on the device is minimized.

Thank you Robert. I feel like I'm going down a rabbit hole! Which program is ideal to overwrite flash memory? I was unable to remove the Opera Browser Account -anyway. I deleted the Google account then realised I may need that to download the tool to overwrite flash memory.

@Padsr Not sure what app to use to overwrite all flash storage, never did this. What should work is using Termux from F-Droid store and use the command mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24903413/150978

Thank you for the help and support Robert - I've spent time searching the web for programs to completely wipe the tablet before factory reset - while not really knowing what I am doing. The one I think I will use is "Forever Gone SD cleaner" as there is a YouTube step-by-step video. - I will let you know how that turns out.

I went to the joint mobile and tablet Google account and was able to 'Sign-out' the tablet, but the tablet still shows, I looked at some online methods - but they don't match what I see on the Google Account, so I couldn't completely delete the tablet, only sign out.
